# Refactor - rename php instead makes file renaming, alt+ shift+r

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pdt

The "Refactor-rename" feature in Eclipse makes file renaming instead of variable renaming re-factoring. This is very annoying.  I have checked my keys settings and I also tried to select from gui but it does not help.

Im right now editing a project with php and JavaScript.The functionality still works well with my java projects. Also it used to work and I think it was broken due to some JavaScript validation process. I also have some JavaScript resource called ECMA 3 browser support that I cannot remove.

---

I tried to download a new eclipse version, change workspace, delete all project settings, delete all user settings. Nothing works. Its just for php files. My collaborators computer also got "infected" so its something project specific which changes the settings of the whole eclipse enviorment...

---

Im now trying to uninstall/install plugins in a bruteforce fashion

Comment: PHP in Eclipse?? Wouldn't be better to use some primarily PHP-oriented IDE?

Comment: Like what? tried several but they are all bad. Blusfish, aptana, geany

Comment: Idk I've heard some people use NetBeans, but it's mainly for Java as well.